# Jquery JavaScript variable is not defined, inexperience caused error

Tags: javascript, jquery, var

So I am new to JavaScript and jQuery and I can't figure out why my variables are "undefined."

This is what I am doing: http://jsfiddle.net/krECX/15/

What I don't understand is why the variable `$asdf` is undefined when I call the `$asdf.length` in this function:

```
function func() {
   var $asdf = $('#inp').value;
   $('#divOfDoom').hide().html("" + $asdf.length).fadeIn('fast');
}
```

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid but every example I have found does something identical to my eyes.

What I have tried:
`var $asdf = createInstance();`
`alert('' + $asdf);` returns 'undefined' regardless of what is in the input box.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var $asdf = $('#inp')[0].value
```

or

```
var $asdf = $('#inp').val()
```

Comment: @sparks Mixing jQuery and JavaScript is a problem that lots of people have trouble with even when they're only new to 1 side of the coin!  Keep it up ;)

Answer (score 3):

Incorrect jQuery syntax:

```
$('#inp').val();
```